# How can i pick a template in drupal 7 while page creation

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I want my Drupal 7 to pick my cutomized template while the time creating the page only, how can I do this, Can some one please...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly the following tpl.php naming syntax maybe what you are looking for:

```
node--[type|nodeid].tpl.php
base template: node.tpl.php

Theme hook suggestions are made based on these factors, 
listed from the most specific template to the least. 
Drupal will use the most specific template it finds:

node--nodeid.tpl.php
node--type.tpl.php
node.tpl.php
```

...or you may want to check out the "Display suite" or "Panels" module for a GUI interface for what I suspect you are trying to do.